# Flutter Syncfusion large PDF

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, syncfusion

I'm developing an app in Flutter and I'm using the *syncfusion_flutter_pdf* to create PDF files.

My problem is that when dealing with large PDF (many pages), it takes a lot of time to save the document with the save() function of the PdfDocument object. Moreover, as this function is writing in the memory, it can cause out of memory issue.

My question is: Is there a way to display the PdfDocument generated with Syncfusion without having to save in memory?

Thanks for your help!

I tried to display a large PDF document created with *syncfusion_flutter_pdf* but it takes too much time

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.